# Unterschied zwischen "es sei denn" und "außer wenn"?

Tags: usage, conjunction

> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, außer wenn ich nicht genug Geld habe.
>
> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, es sei denn, dass ich nicht genug Geld habe.

Gibt es irgendwelche Unterschiede zwischen "es sei denn" und "außer wenn", oder sind die beiden genau das Gleiche? Diese [Webseite](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/wenn-varianten-selbst-wenn-ausser-wenn-es-sei-denn-sonst-andernfalls/), von der auch die Beispiele stammen, behauptet keinen Unterschied.

Comment: Danke sehr Emanuel. Ich sehe da wie!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl lässt *es sei denn* es unwahrscheinlicher erscheinen, dass die Ausnahme eintritt. Wir haben also in etwa folgende Rangfolge:

> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, wenn ich genug Geld habe.
>
> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, außer wenn ich nicht genug Geld habe.
>
> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, es sei denn, dass ich nicht genug Geld habe.

In jedem Satz ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass ich nicht genug Geld habe, geringer als im vorhergehenden, wobei die erste Variante der Neutralität am nächsten kommt.

---

Weiterhin kann *es sei denn* auch als Hauptsatzkonjunktion genutzt werden, also z. B.:

> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, es sei denn, ich habe nicht genug Geld.

Dies ermöglicht gewisse Satzkonstruktionen übersichtlicher zu gestalten (wegen der anderen Wortstellung im Nebensatz). Zum Beispiel vergleiche man:

> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, außer wenn ich nicht genug Resturlaub, Geld zur Finanzierung der Reise oder Zeit, um mein Auto zu reparieren, habe.
>
> Im August fahre ich nach Italien, es sei denn, ich habe nicht genug Resturlaub, Geld zur Finanzierung der Reise oder Zeit, um mein Auto zu reparieren.

Comment: Hm, ich finde den immer noch reichlich unübersichtlich. _Benzin_ scheint mir parallel zu _Geld_ und _Urlaubszeit_ zu sein, das ist aber inhaltlich nicht so sinnvoll (es sei denn, man hätte einen privaten Benzintank im Haus).

Comment: Wo würde Dein Sprachgefühl denn "... es sei denn, ich hätte nicht genug Geld" in das Wahrscheinlichkeitsranking einordnen?

Comment: @chirlu: Ich habe es etwas umgeordnet, und die Behauptung auf *übersichtlicher* abgeschwächt. So groß ist der Übersichtsgewinn nicht, dass er etwas komplett Unübersichtliches leicht übersichtlich machen kann. Jetzt brauche ich nur noch eine sinnvolle Alternative zum Benzin.

Comment: @Matthias: Noch weiter unten, und zwar so weit, dass ich es nicht mehr als unwahrscheinlich, sondern fast unmöglich ansehe (weil ich z. B. Multimillionär bin).

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob "außer" und "es sei denn" tatsächlich eine unterschiedliche starke Wahrscheinlichkeit ausdrücken. Wo ich mir aber sicher bin, dass ich in dem konkreten Italien-Beispiel "es sei denn" natürlicher finde und es in diesem Satz unabhängig von jeglicher Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie dem "außer" vorziehen würde.

Comment: @Em1... stimme voll zu. Für ich sind die Wahrscheinlichkeiten gleich. Auch finde ich "es sei denn, dass" total unschön. Ja, Leute sagen das, aber gut ist es nicht. Und ja, "es sei denn + nicht" klingt für mich deutlich eleganter als "ausser wenn + nicht"

Comment: Statt "außer wenn" würde ich sagen "Im August fahre ich nach Italien, außer ich habe nicht genug Geld."

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe definitiv keinen Unterschied in den durch "es sei denn" bzw. "außer wenn" ausgedrückten Wahrscheinlichkeiten. Allerdings empfinde ich "es sei denn" als deutlich eleganter und "außer wenn" als eher umgangssprachlich.